# Alternativas para o (anti-)padrão Entity-Attribute-Value

Tags: modelagem, estrutura-de-dados, nosql

Estou trabalhando em dois sistemas que possuem uma característica comum: entidades cujos atributos são dinâmicos (i.e. não podem ser "engessados" - *hardcoded*), precisam se consultados em operações de busca (filtro de resultados), mas de outra forma estão desacoplados do restante do sistema (i.e. não há nada fazendo referência a eles, nem eles são usados em nenhum cálculo específico). Estou com dificuldade de encontrar uma forma apropriada para representá-los.

Até o momento, tenho usado o (anti-)padrão [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Há uma tabela `Entity` que identifica a entidade, uma tabela `Tag` (`NxN` com `Entity`) que diz o "tipo" - ou "classe" - da entidade, uma tabela `Attribute` (`Nx1` com `Tag`) que identifica a propriedade, seu tipo, e se pode ou não estar ausente, e por fim várias tabelas `XValue` (`TextValue`, `IntValue`, `DateValue` etc) que dizem "a entidade E possui para o atributo A o valor V".

> Contextualizando, uma entidade poderia ser um produto à venda, sua tag o tipo de produto (ex.: "carro"), os atributos sendo as características de um carro (ex.: "marca", "modelo", "quilômetros rodados") e os valores a aplicação daquelas características ao produto à venda (ex.: "Fiat", "Palio", "20000"). Tipos de produtos podem ser criados, alterados e excluídos (dinâmicos), pode-se consultar um tipo de produto pelas seus características (ex.: filtrar carros pela marca "Fiat"), mas não há qualquer chave estrangeira para um atributo específico, e *jamais* haverá qualquer cálculo "não genérico" envolvendo características de produtos.
>
> E, como falei, atualmente implemento isso na forma de modelos EAV - num banco de dados PostgreSQL, *cross-platform* a princípio porém mais voltado pra Linux.

Normalmente o uso de EAV é um "alerta de WTF em potencial", mas creio que esse seria um dos seus usos legítimos (as estruturas dos dados modeladas dessa forma são realmente **dados**, e não **meta-dados**). A grande maioria do banco está formalizada, apenas umas poucas entidades foram modeladas dessa forma (e tomei medidas pra garantir que seria possível formalizar qualquer modelo que porventura venha a ser acoplado ao restante do sistema).

Entretanto, estou procurando por **alternativas** a esse modelo - já que ele é trabalhoso de se lidar e cheio de *pitfalls*. Pensei em representar cada entidade por um simples XML, mas há o requisito da busca filtrada - o que não sei como fazer [de forma eficiente]. Não tenho experiência com SGBDs não relacionais (["NoSQL"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)), por isso não sei se suas características de performance seriam aceitáveis (estou prevendo um número elevado de leituras - buscas filtradas - simultâneas, bem como escritas simultâneas - ainda que não *na mesma entidade*). Outras ideias me vieram à cabeça, mas me parecem "malucas" demais pra se usar na prática (ex.: alterar dinamicamente o esquema do BD sempre que um "tipo" é modificado).

Peço que as respostas se baseiem em **experiência prévia** envolvendo sistemas com requisitos semelhantes, não somente opinião e/ou base teórica, se possível. Sugestões de tecnologias específicas são bem vindas, mas o que eu busco é mais uma **estratégia de solução**, e não uma *recomendação de software*.

---

**Atualização:** Para quem não está familiarizado com o "Entity-Attribute-Value" (infelizmente não encontrei material algum em português sobre o assunto), aqui está um exemplo concreto:

Numa modelagem tradicional (formalizada), uma entidade "Carro" poderia ser representada assim:

```
Carros
ID      Marca     Modelo     Km
----------------------------------
1       Fiat      Palio      20000
2       Honda     Fit        10000
```

Numa modelagem EAV, isso é feito assim:

```
Entidades         Atributos            Valores
ID   Tipo         ID    Nome           Entidade Atributo Valor
----------        -------------        -----------------------
1    Carro        1     Marca          1        1        Fiat
2    Carro        2     Modelo         1        2        Palio
                  3     Km             1        3        20000
                                       2        1        Honda
                                       2        2        Fit
                                       2        3        10000
```

A vantagem dessa representação é que o tipo "Carro" não está engessado (*hardcoded*): se eu quiser adicionar um atributo "Cor", eu não preciso mexer na estrutura da tabela, criar *queries* novas pra lidar com esse atributo, etc - basta criar uma linha a mais na tabela `Atributos` e para cada carro uma linha a mais na tabela `Valores`. Se além de carros eu quiser representar outra coisa (ex.: imóveis), é só criar linhas na tabela `Entidades` com esse novo tipo, e dar-lhe atributos da mesma forma que a "Carros".

As desvantagens são... bem, [todas as possíveis e imagináveis](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20763/5546)! De um modo geral, esse é um padrão a ser evitado a todo custo (i.e. um "anti-padrão"). Entretanto, mesmo os maiores críticos admitem que - em certos casos - ele é inevitável. Minha pergunta é: 1) isso se aplica ao meu caso? ou há uma maneira formalizada de atender aos meus requisitos? 2) se é inevitável, se existem boas alternativas que possuam performance aceitável.

Comment: Eu não consegui entender, ... ?

Comment: @HarryPotter Qual parte? Se algo não está claro na pergunta, me indique o que é e eu acrescento mais detalhes.

Comment: Eu to tentando entender o fio da meada, em relação a tal configuração que é dinâmica, eu já li algumas vezes e cada vez que eu leio fico mais confuso, gostei muito da questão em si, mas, se puder coloque um exemplo que venha na sua cuca quero tentar ajudar, porque, é a parte da programação que mais gosto !!! Não sei se vou conseguir mas, quem sabe!

Comment: @HarryPotter Coloquei um exemplo, espero que fique mais claro. De todo modo, nesses dias em que não tive uma resposta venho pesquisando por alternativas. Se até eu chegar numa solução ninguém postar nenhuma resposta, eu documento aqui o que descobri...

Comment: Será que você não está procurando pelo em ovo? Pela descrição o modelo EAV funciona perfeitamente para o seu caso. Não precisa ter tanto medo dele assim. Eu tenho experiência com um sistema que usa uma derivação desse modelo levada ao extremo, e apesar dos WTFs (que no seu caso parecem bem sob controle) ainda vejo vários pontos positivos.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, vou dar uma analisada, achei muito interessante!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Esse é um caso de uso típico para ferramentas NoSQL, em especial para ferramentas da família de [bancos de dados orientados à documentos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) (como o [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)). Outras alternativas possíveis / complementares são ferramentas de [*enterprise search*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_search) (como o [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)).

A palavra chave aqui é *schema-less*, uma característica com vantagens e desvantagens (veja [essa apresentação](http://martinfowler.com/articles/schemaless/) do Martin Fowler sobre o assunto).

Tive boas experiência com grandes sistemas de:

- **E-commerce** ⇒ Geralmente possuem modelos relacionais complicadíssimos para representar atributos / grupos de atributos / hierarquia de categorias / atributos de categorias. etc.
- **Vagas e Currículos** ⇒ Geralmente lidam com Informação textual pouco estruturada. Algoritmos para determinar relevância são extremamente importantes.
- **Telco** ⇒ Armazenam configurações diversas e difíceis de estruturar em modelo relacional.

Na verdade, a partir de um determinado volume de dados, bem como para determinadas características de leitura e escrita, *enterprise search*, NoSQL ou ambas as coisas são praticamente necessárias para manter o sistema responsivo.

### Como funciona

Em ambos os casos é possível criar documentos com atributos diversos (e.g., em formato JSON), inclusive atributos complexos (*arrays*, tipos aninhados, etc). Documentos com atributos diferentes podem ser agrupados na mesma categoria (ou seja, o tipo de um documento não define seus atributos).

Quando você busca por determinado documento (por exemplo, por *id*), recebe toda a informação que persistiu sobre aquele documento (i.e., todos os atributos).

Quando você faz uma consulta usando determinado atributo as *engines* fazem uma busca apenas nos documentos que contém aquele atributo.

Na prática sua aplicação acaba conhecendo e definindo as regras para os atributos (e.g., um carro sempre vai ter `id`, `modelo` e `ano`, mas apenas carros importados possuem o atributo país de origem) e você faz consultas "sãs" em cima dessas regras. É o que o Martin Fowlwer chama de *schemas* implícitos.

### Características

**Performance:** O uso correto dessas soluções é bem mais eficiente do que o padrão *EVA* em bancos de dados relacionais. Essas soluções são feitas para escalar e retornar rapidamente resultados de consultas em *data sets* gigantes.

**Consultas:** Buscas por tipos, ranges, buscas lógicas, ordenação, *scoring*, *full text search*, enfim, todo tipo de coisa pode ser feita. É claro que as ferramentas possuem suas próprias características. Leva um tempo até você entender como estruturar as informações de forma eficiente, bem como perder o vício em funções agregadas, cláusulas *having* e coisas do gênero (ainda que mesmo esse tipo de consulta possa ser feita com soluções de [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)).

**ACID / BASE**: Assim como em bancos de dados relacionais, ferramentas NoSQL geralmente podem ser configuradas para suportar diferentes características de consistência / disponibilidade / tolerância à falha (veja [Teorema de CAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)). Cada ferramenta também possui seus mecanismos de transação e serialização* .

**Praticidade:** Persista seus documentos e faça todo tipo de consulta (bem como *updates*, *deletes*, *updates* parciais, etc). Tudo é bem simples (a curva de aprendizagem de SGBDs Relacionais, ao meu ver, é bem mais acentuada).

* Específico para as ferramentas mencionadas: Você não terá nenhum problema com leituras ou escritas concorrentes. Apenas recomendo que mantenha ao menos dois nós no ar o tempo todo (especialmente para o MongoDB). O intuído aqui não é (apenas) garantir alta disponibilidade, e sim extrair o máximo das ferramentas. Recomendo fazer isso mesmo para o ambiente de desenvolvimento... Essa tarefa é bem mais simples do que aparenta (eu fiz configurações locais com VMs no meu laptop, não perdi mais do que uma hora configurando o MongoDB e o Elasticsearch).