# Database com extra headers

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Alguém conhece algum banco de dados no qual, além da arquitetura tradicional (linhas e colunas), poderíamos criar e manipular CAMPOS, que estariam disponíveis para leitura e escrita e que poderiam ser manipulados via SQL?

Exemplo:

Extra Header da tabela CLIENTES:

```
+-----------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|NOME DO CAMPO    | TIPO   | VALOR                       |
+-----------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|VENDAS_01        |DOUBLE  | 0.00                        |
+-----------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|VENDAS_02        |DOUBLE  | 0.00                        |
+-----------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|VENDAS_03        |DOUBLE  | 0.00                        |
+-----------------+--------+-----------------------------+
|TAXA_XPTO        |DOUBLE  | 0.00                        |
+-----------------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

A tabela CLIENTES:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
|CLIENTE_ID       |NOME             | CEP       |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
|                1|PEDRO SILVA      |03232-000  |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
|                2|PEDRO SOUZA      |03232-001  |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
|                3|PEDRO COSTA      |03232-001  |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes, por exemplo, qual o cenário da utilização e exemplo da utilização deste modelo? Aparentemente o única abordagem que se encaixa nesta descrição seria o NOSQL, mas, como o próprio nome já diz, consultas SQL não permitidas. Em alguns BD NOSQL até pode-se usar SQL, porém, de forma limitada.

Comment: O cenário é muito amplo e vasto. As possibilidades seriam incrivelmente produtivas. Poderíamos por exemplo, fazer uma SELECT do tipo: SELECT * FROM CLIENTES HEADER: VENDAS_01, VENDAS_02, ou um UPDATE CLIENTES SET 'PEDRO COUTO' WHERE CLIENTE_ID=2 HEADER: VENDAS_02 = 1300.52, VENDAS_02 = 3500.12

Comment: Relacionado: ["Alternativas para o (anti-)padrão Entity-Attribute-Value"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15534/215)

Answer (score 4):

Até onde eu sei nenhum banco de dados relacional faz isso "nativamente". Por outro lado o resultado é possível em qualquer banco de dados relacional.

Falo em relacional porque parece haver o requisito de usar SQL que é fundamentalmente usado em banco de dados relacionais.

## NoSQL

De fato existem diversos bancos de dados não relacionais, em geral os chamados [NoSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101), são feitos para isto mesmo. Se o recurso é importante e o volume de dados é grande, é recomendável optar por uma ferramenta como essa.

## Entity-Attribute-Value

Se for necessário o uso de um modelo relacional para atender esta necessidade pode-se adotar o modelo [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

O máximo que um banco de dados poderia fazer é criar algumas facilidades para esconder a implementação disso, seria praticamente um *syntax sugar*. Acredito que nenhum se deu ao trabalho de fazer isso não só porque foge do padrão estabelecido no SQL e seu uso não é universal mas também porque é trivial fazer isto manualmente.

De fato seu exemplo mostra como fazer. Teria duas tabelas e as consultas e manipulação de dados aconteceriam como foi mostrado no comentário, só teria uma sintaxe um pouco diferente, óbvio.

Então o banco de dados ter isso pronto poderia ser um pouco mais produtivo mas não muito mais. E teria um problema, muitas pessoas não entendem bem o funcionamento dos SGDBs e provavelmente abusariam disto achando que é feito de forma mágica e sem custo. Não seria fácil os softwares gerenciadores fazerem nada muito melhor do que o programador/DBA faria manualmente. Talvez em alguns casos o manual pode trazer melhor performance.

Tenho que dizer que o ideal é evitar este tipo de composição, ela tem problemas de performance. Claro que para certos volumes isto não é problema, e se você precisa mesmo é uma ferramenta válida desde que saiba os compromissos (onde está se metendo).

A forma como as tabelas são definidas funcionam de uma certa forma como linguagens estáticas, ou seja, as estruturas são definidas antecipadamente e o banco de dados garante que sempre seja usado desta forma. Usar o EAV é como usar uma linguagem dinâmica onde a estrutura de dados é menos importante e a aplicação deve se virar para que tudo funcione direito, deve sempre ver se a estrutura está de acordo com o que ela espera ou deve se adaptar para funcionar com o que encontrou.

Quando você usa esta técnica está abrindo mão do esquema que é tão importante no modelo relacional. Mas ela não é considerada errada, na verdade é recomendada pela [sexta forma de normalização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form). Mas note que [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) se preocupa com o modelo e não com a performance ou outros compromissos.

Vale um lida em [Alternativas para o (anti-)padrão Entity-Attribute-Value](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15534/101).

## Outras soluções

Alguns bancos de dados ajudam esse dinamismo sem usar uma tabela extra o que pode ser bem vantajoso do ponto de vista de performance.

O [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) por exemplo permite que qualquer coluna possa ter qualquer tipo de valor. Não quer dizer que isto seja recomendado, mas sabendo usar pode ser útil. Aí você pode colocar essas colunas extras dentro da própria tabela que elas pertencem. Não resolve tudo mas ajuda. Também pode [simular *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118702/101).

O [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) possuem *arrays* que podem simular essas colunas extras. Também há limitações mas pode ser suficiente.

Na verdade qualquer banco de dados pode fazer o mesmo usando uma coluna `varchar` que se responsabilize por armazenar todas essas colunas extras. Teria que acessar esses dados de forma apropriada. Claro que para facilitar serão necessários *views*, *triggers*, *stored procedures* e *functions*. Tudo tem um preço.

No artigo da Wikipedia do padrão EAV mostra que o SQL Server 2008 permite que [colunas podem ser definidas sem ocupar espaço](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#Consideration_for_SQL_Server_2008_and_later:_Sparse_columns), o que pode ser útil em alguns destes cenários.

O mesmo artigo mostra que existem [bancos específicos na nuvem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#EAV_and_cloud_computing) que conseguem manter características relacionais e de NoSQL.

Dependendo do que se deseje, uma coluna XML ou JSON, como é comum ter em vários sistemas atuais, pode ser a solução. Ele subverte um pouco o modelo relacional mas dá a flexibilidade necessária. Os DBs relacionais começaram colocar este tipo de coluna justamente para competir com os NoSQL. Alguns até possuem outras ferramentas que ajudam aproximá-los do modelo desestruturado do NoSQL. Veja mais no [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#Alternative_XML).

Você poderá criar uma estrutura de árvore conforme eu já [perguntei aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/101).

Mas estas são apenas tentativas de otimização do modelo EAV que provavelmente é o que vai resolver o que você quer.

## Conclusão

Lembre-se que não importa muito a forma que use você perderá ou dificultará o uso de certas características de um DB relacional. Isto pode ser crítico ou irrisório.

Pode ser só um exemplo e eu posso não ter visto o todo mas o que você mostrou me parece um caso para colunas comuns ou para normalização comum e não para colunas dinâmicas.

Este padrão deve ser usado com dados semiestruturados, ou seja, nem é um texto puro, nem dá para organizar os dados que serão armazenados de forma consistente e absolutamente padronizada. E como demonstrado existem diversas soluções para isto, algumas ajudadas pelo software de DB.

A solução está aí e acho que você até já tinha pensado nela, só não tem com a facilidade que você deseja, talvez porque a maioria das outras pessoas não deseje. Certamente não é porque não dá para fazer ou porque ninguém pensou nisto antes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Agradeço a sua atenção e as informações e referências, que sem dúvida, foram muito úteis e interesssantes.

O que mais se aproxima da idéia, parece ser o caso citado do SQL Server 2008, mas me parece que perderia o seu potencial face a manipulação. 

Enfim, é uma discussão saudável e produtiva. Estamos em pleno avanço tecnológico. A nossa criatividade é limitada a disponibilidade. Obrigado mais uma vez pela atenção e espero poder um dia utilizar o MySQL com essa implementação.

Comment: Novas idéias foram sempre objeto de resistência e contestação, mesmo sem ter a comprovada prova de sua ineficiência (é o caso do avião). A partir do momento em que a coisa funcionou, permanece até hoje a discussão de quem é o pai da idéia.

Comment: @HumbertoWilsonRondeico você não precisa fazer isto agora ou se não achar que deve mas se a resposta lhe atendeu bem você pode aceitá-la como correto. E quando tiver pontos suficientes, poderá votar em todos os *posts* do *site*. Veja o [tour].