# Armazenar vetor no SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, array, sqlite, modelagem

Estou criando uma aplicação em `C#` que deve possuir um banco de dados. A princípio estou pensando em utilizar o SQlite pela simplicidade. Porém para cada dado inserido no meu banco deve possuir :

- Itentificador (`int`, `char`, `bool`)...
- Vetor (que pode ser de tamanho como 2,10000)

O problema é como armazenar esse vetor, sendo que o SQLite não aceita vetores.

Já pesquisei algumas soluções, mas tenho dúvidas sobre essas opções e em relação a seus problemas.

#### 1 - Armazenar como uma string:

Existe algum problema armazenar strings muito grandes? De qualquer forma meu valores são `float` ou `double`, e convertendo para `string`, facilmente vou estar perdendo informações, então não sei se esse é uma boa solução.

#### 2 - Criar novas tabelas para cada nova entrada:

Assim eu teria uma tabela principal e para cada novo dado entrada precisaria criar uma nova tabela. A solução pode ser interessante, mas um banco de dados com muitas tabelas (10000 tabelas) não poderia ficar lento?

Gostaria de uma dessas duas opções acima se alguma delas pode funcionar bem, ou então me indicar uma outra alternativa a um banco de dados que eu possa colocar vetores como elementos da tabela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução pode ser usar um tipo `CHARACTER` mesmo. Ou `BLOB` para dar mais liberdade de criar um formato que permita qualquer dado sem serialização específica, e possivelmente economizando espaço. Não dá para afirmar qual o melhor para cada caso. Não é problema pelo tamanho, ambos aceitam dados bem grandes.

Obviamente que a sintaxe das *queries* SQL não está preparada para manipular os dados internos do que seria esse vetor inserido dentro de outro tipo. Se precisar manipular os elementos individualmente em consultas SQL precisará criar funções personalizadas (possivelmente em C) para uso, adotando o formato que você adotar.

Lembrando que o SQLite tem tipagem dinâmica e as colunas possuem afinidade e não tipo fixo.

Faz parte da filosofia do banco de dados ter só os tipos básicos e utilizá-los para resolver todas necessidades mais complexas, como esta do vetor.

A escolha entre essa solução e tabelas [normalizadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) depende de cada caso. Na maioria dos casos eu só adotaria a normalização para resolver a questão se as consultas pedirem isto, se o domínio indicar que deva ser separado e que a performance não for afetada.

Na verdade não vejo porque precisaria 10 mil tabelas, nem faz sentido fazer isso, seria difícil administrar. Vejo a necessidade de duas, uma principal e a outra que conteria os dados dos vetores.

Esta segunda tabela teria uma coluna indicando a qual linha da tabela principal ela está vinculada e uma coluna com o número do elemento do vetor, estas formam em conjunto a chave primária. Eventualmente poderia ter uma só coluna que contivesse uma chave montada com esses dados, mas duvido que seja uma boa solução. Tem ainda, claro, a coluna onde realmente guarda o valor (poderia até ser várias colunas, se necessário, se o vetor guarda um objeto complexo com vários membros em cada elemento).

Em muitos casos essa solução é mais simples e padronizada, mas não garanto que é a melhor para tudo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado bigown. Só uma dúvida. Se fizer como você disse, usando apenas duas tabelas, eu teria uma tabela principal com o cadastro (que poderia atingir 10mil linhas), e um segunda tabela, relacionadas pela chave primária. Nessa segunda tabela para cada linha da tabela 1, eu teria (10mil linhas, que são os vetores). Assim poderia chegar a ter uma tabela com 100.000.000 linhas,  com 6 ou 7 colunas. Não vou ter problema com essa massa de dados usando o SQLLite. Ele vai dar conta?

Comment: De jeito algum. O SQLite lida muito bem com esses volumes sem soluçar.  Eventualmente a criação de algum índice pode ser útil. Essas otimizações são necessárias em qualquer DB nas mais diversas situações. O bichinho é parrudo e para quase tudo não fica devendo para outras soluções.