# Como escolher entre NoSQL e SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mongodb, nosql

Os bancos de dados NoSQL estão aí, e uma dúvida que sempre tenho ao iniciar um projeto é quais critérios utilizar para escolher entre um banco relacional ou não.

Como avaliar o meu projeto para saber a melhor opção para ele?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Não dá para responder magicamente, e a resposta sempre será genérica. É apenas sobre levantar os requisitos, entender todas as tecnologias candidatas com profundidade para saber o que realmente ela resolve, suas deficiências e fazer uma projeção do que se pretende em cima do que vai usar para avaliar se aquilo atende ao que necessita. Em muitos casos teria que fazer protótipos para "ver" se atende ao que quer. Precisa de experiência para não errar.

Se a pessoa fizer isso muito provavelmente ela decidirá por usar o SQL e não o NoSQL. Estou falando de estatística, não de preferência minha.

Note que NoSQL é um pouco geral demais. Tem diversos tipos e cada um pode ser mais adequado que outro. Em geral classifica-se entre:

- chave e valor
- família de colunas
- documento
- grafos

  e alguns outros, possivelmente associados à estes, por exemplo o orientado a objeto que acaba sendo uma especialização do grafo.

## Características de um e outro

#### Consistência e durabilidade

A principal característica dos bancos de dados NoSQL é que a consistência costuma ser deixada de lado. Sua aplicação pode abrir mão da consistência? O Facebook pode. Não importa se todo mundo vê uma publicação no mesmo momento, não importa se o *like* entra atrasado. Mas baixar o estoque ou mudar o saldo bancário pode ser assim? Com NoSQL esqueça transações, atomicidade (geralmente). Mesmo quando alguns produtos digam que podem fazer, sempre tem um porém escondidinho ali.

Na verdade o nome correto deste tipo de tecnologia devia ser NoConsistency porque é isso que realmente não tem. Cada vez mais elas estão usando relações e até SQL.

Muitos bancos de dados NoSQL sequer tem durabilidade e precisa de um meio auxiliar para persistir os dados. Você pode lidar com isso? É adequado ao que precisa.

Percebe que escolher um produto é o que deve fazer. NoSQL é amplo demais. Os bancos de dados relacionais tem a vantagem de serem mais padronizados e é mais fácil compará-los.

#### Dados estruturados

Seus dados não possuem uma estrutura comum? NoSQL costuma funcionar melhor quando os dados são relativamente livres, ou seja, cada entrada costuma ter "campos" diferentes. Justamente porque isso é importante em alguns cenários específicos que os banco de dados relacionais estão apenas dando uma alternativa quando uma parte dos dados não são estruturados. Esse era o principal *selling point* da tecnologia NoSQL, era tão bom que o recurso foi incorporado em todos RDBMS mais usados, ainda que alguns não de forma tão boa assim.

Sua(s) aplicação(ões) é(são) capaz(es) de lidar bem com dados não estruturados, não normalizados? Não é a mesma coisa que usar dados relacionais. Em geral facilita a leitura mas pode criar enormes problemas para a gravação de dados. Além da consistência do banco de dados ser eventual, é mais complicado para o programador manter tudo consistente. Dados não estruturados são difíceis de automatizar.

Em muitos casos o NoSQL costuma ser só um repositório de dados, ele deixa para o programador se virar com o que está ali. Isso pode ser bom ou ruim. O SQL costuma ser uma ferramenta completa de manipulação de dados.

#### Relacionamento de dados

Eu vejo muito as pessoas subestimando a necessidade das relações. Começam fazendo algo com NoSQL, aí as necessidades vão aumentando e o sujeito começa ter que fazer adaptações que vão se afastando do modelo adotado, vão criando dificuldades, trazendo prejuízos para a performance e o que era bom no começo passa ser um pesadelo. Já vi caso que em determinado momento o modelo mudou tanto que acabou virando relacional em uma ferramenta péssima para lidar com relacional.

Você precisará de poucos relatórios ou consultas estruturadas? O modelo relacional fornece melhores ferramentas para isso. Tem certos padrões de acesso a dados que fazem o NoSQL virar uma carroça. Imagine a comparação de fazer 30 buscas em cada linha de dado para montar um relatório e uma busca. Multiplique por milhões de linhas. O NoSQL pode exigir uma busca por campo enquanto o SQL apenas uma busca por linha.

#### Performance

Fala-se muito em boa performance com NoSQL, isso não é tão verdade assim, afinal não existe milagre. Hoje os bancos de dados relacionais possuem boas estratégias para otimização. Em geral o NoSQL obtém performance com muita memória. Este recurso ajuda muito o DB relacional também.

Alguns bancos de dados, como o MongoDB, permitem você escolher se quer mais performance ou ter outras características, como a durabilidade, por exemplo. Mas aí a performance fica semelhante à encontrada no SQL ou outras formas de banco de dados mais estruturados. Com pouca memória, esqueça NoSQL para quase todos cenários. Boa parte nem funciona se não tiver memória suficiente para todo o banco de dados.

Vejo muita gente falando que ele evita *JOIN*. O relacional também se você modelar desta forma. As pessoas não modelam assim porque há desvantagens em fazer isso. As desvantagens não desaparecem no NoSQL. Claro que no passado os DBs baseados em SQL tinham menos ferramentas para facilitar um modelo sem *JOINs*, mas isso mudou. NoSQL, pelo menos em certos modelos, é bom quando os dados costumam estar em um único documento e eles são acessados sempre pelo documento como ponto de entrada, o que é algo inflexível, ou quando precisa fazer tantos acessos para evitar o `JOIN` que ele era preferível.

#### Ferramenta auxiliar

É comum que o NoSQL seja usado como ferramenta auxiliar em grande parte das aplicações. Muitas vezes ele é apenas um cache. Você tem volume suficiente para precisar desse cache?

Este site que está usando agora usa o Redis. Você está fazendo um site que terá o volume de acesso semelhante e que grande parte dos acessos usarão dados repetidos por tempo razoável? Você precisa desse nível de escala? Precisa distribuir os dados em diversos servidores para alcançar os objetivos de escala? O NoSQL costuma ser bom nisto. Vou contra um segredo. Eles usavam muito mais cache que usam hoje, descobriram que o cache mais atrapalhava que ajudava.

Essa é a principal vantagem hoje em dia: escalar a solução nos níveis de internet (mesmo quando não seja uma aplicação de internet. E note que o fato de estar na internet não quer dizer nada, o site simples que tem acesso restrito, de uma imobiliária por exemplo, não precisa disso).

## Informações mais detalhadas

Na verdade boa parte já foi respondido antes em [O que é um banco NoSQL? Como é o seu funcionamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101) e [NoSQL é tão problemático quanto parece?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/101).

Tem uma [pergunta com um exemplo de uso apropriado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53518/101) (ou não).

Leia [um dos melhores artigos sobre o assunto](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/12/6/what-the-heck-are-you-actually-using-nosql-for.html). Um resumo de cenários de uso do NoSQL listado nele:

- Manipulação de *streams* de *log* ou outros dados continuamente atualizados;
- sincronização de dados *offine*;
- necessidades de baixa latência, como jogos;
- jogos online, principalmente os massivos podem se beneficiar mais do *schemaless*;
- sistema de votação (*likes*) e contadores de acesso;
- filas de prioridade;
- dados de sessão;
- análise de dados em cenários específicos (*big data*);
- sites de altíssimo movimento com partes bastante repetitivas;
- onde precisa de relações de grafos, tais como aplicações de recomendação;
- algumas aplicações de mercado financeiro em tempo real.

Propositalmente evitei relacionar aí o que é mais abstrato, já foi colocado anteriormente, ou que o SQL moderno permite fazer o mesmo (exemplo é manter dados descritivos de produtos muito diversos). Principalmente evitei algumas coisas que são tendenciosas ou falsas (pelo menos agora, podem ter sido verdadeiras em 2009).

## MongoDB

O MongoDB especificamente citado na pergunta possui uma [página com indicações de uso](https://www.mongodb.com/use-cases). Pra falar a verdade a página não ajuda muito, parece que eles entenderam que é melhor não dar detalhes porque se for a fundo, 99% das pessoas desistirão dele. Não que o produto seja ruim, apenas não é necessário na maioria dos cenários. Ele certamente tem seu usos, mas já vi muito desavisado passar por experiências horrorosas com o produto (era antes do 4.0, mas a maioria dos problemas permanece). E a culpa é de quem escolheu a tecnologia errada, o produto é bom para os cenários dele.

## Experiência pessoal

Eu vejo uma quantidade imensa de artigos como o NoSQL resolve melhor certos problemas. Alguns são verdade, mas na maioria dos casos: ou a pessoa não sabe usar o SQL (na verdade o modelo relacional) corretamente, inclusive por desconhecimento dos recursos dos bancos de dados, principalmente os mais modernos; ou então está agindo de má fé pra vender sua tecnologia preferida.

Vou repetir o que disse em outra resposta: é desproporcional o que se fala de NoSQL e a real necessidade. Como boa parte do que vemos na internet e mídia em geral.

[image: Como visto na internet]

Tem uma expressão que usamos muito em computação que é muito verdadeira, ao contrário de algumas que não se encaixam em tudo: **a melhor ferramenta é aquela que você conhece**. Se vai usar outra, domine ela antes. Não use porque está na moda. Se a atual você domina e resolve seus problemas, fique com ela. Se fizer certo em uma e errado na outra, a que você fizer certo funcionará melhor que na outra, na maioria dos casos.

Pessoalmente até gosto de deixar o SQL de lado, tenho trabalhado em algo que possivelmente será meu banco de dados preferido e ele é um *no SQL*, será flexível quanto ao modelo, atendendo um pouco de tudo, mas priorizará o modelo relacional. A performance é promissora em todos os casos e exige pouco *scale up*. A única coisa que eu sei que ele será apenas suficientemente escalável, e não será tão fácil fazer *scale out*.

É muito comum o NoSQL dar uma ilusão inicial dele ser mais fácil de manipular. Isto acontece porque ele é mais simples, **menos poderoso**, uma hora vem a conta. Se você não tiver uma base sólida pode nunca perceber o buraco que se meteu.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Resposta bem interessante, me fez rever vários pontos que eu ainda não tinha levado em consideração. Em relação a estrutura de dados, poderíamos colocar que o Mongoose atende bem essa necessidade no MongoDB, mas ainda assim é um ODM, logo não pode ser considerado uma característica do banco de dados em si.

Comment: +1 Fiz uma pergunta recentemente sobre isso, mas essa resposta me ajudou também. Estou procurando entender um pouco mais do Mongo DB e do DynamoDB, da Amazon. Esse último me pareceu muito mais fácil e também barato, em relação ao MongoDB, além de em tese ter mais recursos, mas não dá para saber quão útil tais recursos são.

Comment: Post claramente tendencioso a favor do SQL. Quanto ao argumento de no inicio os bancos de dados NoSQL darem a ilusão de serem melhores, tanto dá para o NoSQL como para o SQL. Todos os bancos de dados vazios são bons.

Comment: @alves é uma opinião. Várias pessoas bem experientes leram o mesmo texto e acharam diferente. Seria bom avaliar se não está vendo isso com tendência. Seu comentário faz parece que o texto só fala mal do NoSQL, o que não é verdade e todos podem ver. O texto mostra que o SQL tende ser uma melhor solução para maioria dos cenários, mas não todos, e cita onde o NoSQL pode ser bem usado. Por anos vieram várias pessoas aqui concordando com isso. Se você tem base pode mostrar o contrário em uma resposta. E por favor não mude minhas palavras para poder argumentar, isso é tendencioso e desonesto.