# MySQL x MongoDB - Exemplos de Apps

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Cite exemplos de aplicações, sites que seria mais indicado a utilizar MySQL (ou qualquer outro SGDB) ou MongoDB. E o motivo?

Pois ainda não consigo ver cenários que o MongoDB seja melhor..

Comment: Veja [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122452/como-escolher-entre-nosql-e-sql) pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

**Altas cargas de escrita**

O MongoDB por padrão prefere altas taxas de inserção ao invés da segurança da transação. Se você precisar carregar toneladas de linhas de dados com um valor de negócio baixo para cada um, MongoDB deve servir. Não faça isso com a gravação de transações US $ 1 milhão ou pelo menos nestes casos faça com uma segurança extra.

**Seus Dados são Baseados por Localização**

MongoDB foi construído em funções espaciais, de modo que para encontrar dados relevantes a partir de locais específicos é rápido e preciso.

Encontrei numa pesquisa rápida, [aqui](https://mongodbwise.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/quando-usar-mongodb-ao-inves-de-mysql-ou-outro-rdbms/).

Comment: para encontrar dados relevantes a partir de locais específicos. O que seria locais especificos?