# Qual tecnologia e motodologia escolher para desenvolver um app?

Tags: app

Qual a melhor tecnologia e motodologia escolher para desenvolver um app?

Comment: Você já decidiu quais tecnologias vai utilizar e, sinceramente, espero que as escolheu com base nos requisitos da aplicação, então qual o objetivo com a pergunta?

Comment: Eu pedi por mais ideias, informações. Se eu ja tivesse escolhido a tecnologia ou soubesse escolhe-las, não teria utilizado o stackoverflow. mas agradeço seu comentário. Tenha um ótimo dia.

Comment: Na verdade, não pediu. Talvez foi a intenção pedir, mas não deixou claro na pergunta. A pergunta consistia em um relato sobre as tecnologias que iria utilizar e a questão "Qual seria a forma mais rápida?", o que inclusive não deixava claro se esse mais rápido fazia referência ao tempo de desenvolvimento considerando as tecnologias que havia listado, de forma a reduzir o prazo de entrega, ou se era uma questão de performance, para a aplicação responder em um menor tempo, também considerando as tecnologias citadas. [...]

Comment: [...] Em ambas as situações não era questionado se as tecnologias escolhidas eram suficientes. E se tivesse feito, a pergunta também seria fechada porque isso depende diretamente dos requisitos, então precisaria listá-los todos na pergunta. Mesmo fazendo isso provavelmente teria uma questão de opinião, pois muitas tecnologias poderiam atender aos requisitos e você iria escolher a que preferir. Questões sobre opinião não fazem parte do escopo da comunidade, como deve ter visto ao fazer o [tour].

Comment: Visto que editou a pergunta com o comentário "*Moderador deixou claro que minha pergunta não deveria ser feita no stack. não entendi o porque, mas tudo bem.*", espero que eu tenha esclarecido os pontos que não estavam claros. Se ainda restou alguma dúvida, pode utilizar o [meta]. Lá só tratamos de assuntos relacionados ao funcionamento do site e comunidade. Quanto atingir pelo menos 20 pontos de reputação você poderá participar ativamente do [chat oficial](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha). Lá podemos discutir esses assuntos livremente :D

Comment: Meu caro, se eu soubesse perguntar isso tudo eu não precisaria fazer a pergunta, eu iria diretamente no google. Mas eu tive uma boa resposta que era o que eu procurava, vou usar seu comentário para padronizar minhas próximas perguntas, agradeço de coração e me desculpa se você se sentiu ofendido algum momento, eu nunca fiz perguntas em foruns, minha vida toda eu so lia os posts e respostas, mas um dia a gente tem que começar de algum lugar não é mesmo? Paz.

Comment: Sem ofensas, só respondi para lhe orientar melhor sobre o funcionamento do site :D

Comment: Confesso que no começo fiquei ofendido, mas vou aprendendo, agradeço sua crítica. Aprendendo a cada comentário.

Comment: Perdão por isso, como os comentários são pequenos, busco sempre ser o mais direto possível, às vezes pode ser entendido de forma errada. O formato do [pt.so] é bem diferente do que muitas pessoas estão acostumadas e sentem muita dificuldade ao começar a utilizar. Você pode ler mais sobre em com essas perguntas no meta [link 1](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/5878), [link 2](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/5878), [link 3](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/105/5878), [link 4](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/5878)

Comment: Como comentei, o [meta] é justamente para isso. Ficou com alguma dúvida? Achou que algo foi ofensivo? Discorda de alguma atitude? Viu alguma coisa feita errada e não sabe como reverter? Posta lá que discutimos o que aconteceu e o que pode ser feito.

Comment: Vou devorar essas páginas, agradeço a paciência.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Bom, forma mais rápida nem sempre é a melhor. Por exemplo, PHP realmente é muito utilizado ainda, mas já não é mais uma das novas tecnologias.

Eu sempre aconselho, principalmente quando ainda não existe nada criado, a escolher a linguagem JS. Isso por que, com uma única linguagem, é possível você ser fullstack (tanto front quanto backend).

Além disso, para Front-end aconselho React, já que com uma única tecnologia e com pouco aprendizado a mais, você já consegue desenvolver aplicativo com React Native.

Você não chegou a fazer qual banco de dados irá utilizar, mas também sempre aconselho NoSQL. Tem vários benefícios, sendo: mais rápido, fácil integração com JS (MongoDB), rápido aprendizado, não usa-se muita porcaria como JOINs, etc.

Para API, aconselho trabalhar com tecnologia serverless. Para isso, pode optar por AWS, GCP ou Azure, inclusive com milhares de solicitações para API de forma GRÁTIS! Eu, por exemplo, uso AWS Lambda e faço em Javascript.

Bom, é muita coisa nova para estudar, porém o custo benefício compensa, mesmo que demore um pouco mais para lançar. É melhor já iniciar por novas tecnologias do que depois querer migrar um sistema já em produção, e ainda mais para outra linguagem.

Comment: Olá Gleidson, agradeço pela resposta que abriu minha mente. Agora é estudar essas tecnologias. Abraço.

Comment: A sugestão de iniciar com JS porque pode ser usado no front/back é válida, mas não suficiente para a decisão em um projeto. Como não fica claro os requisitos em questão, podemos (e devemos) considerar a possibilidade de existirem requisitos que invalidam a escolha do JS. Performance pode ser um, dado que JS não é mil maravilhas nisso, mas podem haver outras limitações como gerenciamento de memória e estruturas da própria linguagem/motor de execução. [...]

Comment: [...] Sobre sugerir o uso de banco de dados NoSQL e serverless eu julgo ser completamente questionável sem conhecer os requisitos. Ambos são tecnologias que buscam resolver problemas bem específicos e sem saber se esses problemas existem não há como saber se são, de fato, as melhores opções. [Como escolher entre NoSQL e SQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/5878)

Comment: Cara, eu achava que não sabia nada, agora tenho certeza! se possível uma dica para estudar algo para entender essas necessidades? Muito obrigado.

Comment: Ele saiu da faculdade há pouco tempo, mal sabe das tecnologias existentes atualmente. Sobre JS ser lento, de onde tu tirou isso? Ainda mais se comprado com PHP!? Sobre NoSQL, a maioria dos projetos dá para usar, assim como serverless também. Claro que em algumas situações especificas, não dá para usar. Mas como ele citou no próprio enunciado, se trata de uma CRM, e o mesmo é totalmente possível ser utilizado NoSQL e Serverless. Agradeço por ter colocado o link para mais explicações mesmo pendendo mais para o lado do relacional. Eu já conheço isso, mas será útil para o William.

Comment: Sobre o link que mandou, a primeira resposta disse: 'Fala-se muito em performance com NoSQL. Isso não é tão verdade assim, afinal não existe milagre.'. Realmente, não existe milagre, mas existe TECNOLOGIA. Ou você ainda continua usando javascript puro quando já existe JQuery, Angular, Vue, React, etc? No passado, não existia ESPAÇO FÍSICO (HD), e por isso foi criado o relacional. Hoje esse não é mais um problema, mas sim o processamento computacional. O db relacional existe um limite para se aumentar o processamento nas buscas, que inclusive pode ser prejudicado após inserir tantos nós.

Comment: Não sei o seu conhecimento sobre tais ferramentas, se realmente utiliza NoSQL e Serverless. Concordo que somente com o meu comentário ele não pode simplesmente definir e utilizar tais tecnologias. Mas acredito que foi muito melhor dar algumas opções do que simplesmente falar pra ele que o post dele estava errado, e não sugeriu nada de útil. William, usar tecnologia só por que já sabe é tão ruim quanto usar uma que não sabe. Estude, pesquise, faça testes, pergunte, planeje seu projeto e veja os possíveis problemas sobre cada tecnologia. Boa sorte com seu projeto!

Comment: Se usa muito javascript puro quando jquery, angular, etc não são necessários. Também é uma questão de requisitos. Muito do que colocou como sugestão parte mais de preferências pessoais suas do que dos requisitos, ou seja, da sua opinião. Por isso a pergunta foi fechada (e devidamente orientado sobre o funcionamento do site).

Comment: Valeu mais uma vez Gleidson, eu realmente consegui ter uma noção do que preciso, não decidi a tecnologia ainda, mas ja li bastante sobre o que me falou, me desculpem por arrumar essa discussão. Agora eu ja estou vendo qual a melhor tecnologia pro meu projeto. Agradeço a todos pela atenção.

Comment: Eu acho informações que iludem as pessoas são muito piores que nada. Informações parciais, tendenciosas, sem considerar o contexto da pessoa, principalmente dadas para quem não tem noção daquilo e não tem senso crítico só ajuda ela levar pro buraco. Pra quem está a beira do precipício um empurrãozinho inociente que seria pra ajudar a pessoa ir pra frente pode ser a morte dela. Pra evitar isso que tem perguntas não são adequadas aqui e são melhores em redes sociais onde vale o quanto pior melhor. Não entro no mérito da resposta que nem li porque qualquer uma para a pergunta é inadequada.

Comment: Blz brow! vai na paz!

Comment: Eu li a resposta agora. Cada negativo é merecido. Meu conselho já que é o que a resposta faz, é fazer tudo ao contrário, ou seja, só usar tecnologias maduras com resultados comprovados, em vez se se iludir com o que está na moda e tem sido o responsável por ter softwares cada vez piores. Ressalto que falar no geral serve para nada, io que deve ser usado só quem entende o problema específico por completo pode dizer, isso se a pessoa tiver larga experiência qualitativa (quem passou a vida toda seguindo receitas só tem experiência quantitativa).