# Como funciona o (anti-)padrão EAV (Entity Attribute Value)?

Tags: banco-de-dados, design-pattern, modelagem, key-value

Gostaria de um exemplo funcional, pois não entendo muito bem essa relação dinâmica de criar tabela de tipos, com tabela de dados, uma relação dinâmica, que muitos a consideram confusa.

Comment: Relacionado: [Alternativas para o anti-padrão Entity-Attribute-Value](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15534/91)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Funcionamento

Ele é muito simples. Em vez de ter as tabelas e colunas, como se conhece bem no modelo relacional, há alguma(s) tabela(s) com basicamente duas colunas, um par de chave e valor.

Na chave há uma identificação de qual é a coluna de dados que está usando ali e um identificador único do que seria a linha (algo como o `id` que costumamos usar nas tabelas). Eventualmente é possível que essa chave seja separada em duas colunas (uma delas pode ser a que tabela virtual a coluna pertence).

O valor é igual ao que você teria em uma coluna mesmo. Mas como na maioria dos bancos de dados o tipo da coluna tem tipo estático, tem que optar por alguma convenção para gravar todos dados. Pode ser um tipo caractere sem tamanho limite.

Obviamente que é preciso um dicionário de dados indicando as colunas, os tipos reais de dados para que possa haver uma conversão quando precisa dos dados com tipagem "certa" e fornecer outras informações relevantes. Esse dicionário pode estar no banco de dados ou só na aplicação.

Há casos extremos que existe apenas uma tabela e a chave conta ainda com uma informação adicional identificando de qual tabela de dados aquele dado se refere. Costuma ser um *anti pattern*.

Pense em algo assim:

```
CREATE TABLE TABELA (
    TABELA INT NOT NULL,
    COLUNA INT NOT NULL,
    LINHA INT NOT NULL,
    VALOR VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (TABELA, COLUNA, LINHA));
```

Tudo é gravado aí. Em alguns casos os identificadores de tabela e coluna são textos com o nome, o que pode ser pior ainda por gerar um acesso mais lento e ocupar mais espaço.

Se tivesse tabelas assim:

```
CREATE TABLE PESSOA (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NOME VARCHAR(60),
    NASCTO DATE,
    SALARIO MONEY);

CREATE TABLE DIVIDA (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CLIENTE INT,
    VENCTO DATE,
    VALOR MONEY);
```

Transpondo para EAV seria gravado assim:

```
INSERT INTO TABELA (TABELA, COLUNA, LINHA, VALOR) VALUES
                   (1, 1, 1, "JOÃO"), //nome da pessoa linha 1
                   (1, 2, 1, "15/07/1980"), //nascto
                   (1, 3, 1, "2000,00"), //salario
                   (1, 1, 2, "JOSÉ"), //linha 2 da pessoa
                   (1, 2, 2, "28/10/1986"),
                   (1, 3, 2, "1500,00"),
                   (2, 1, 1, "1"), //tabela divida, relaciona pessoa 1
                   (2, 2, 1, "20/08/2016"), //vencto
                   (2, 3, 1, "100,00"); //valor
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/EAV.sql).

Imagine a dificuldade de fazer relações com esses dados. Imagine como otimizações são mais complicadas. Imagine quanta confusão ocorrerá por todos os dados serem gravados como texto, usando uma técnica chamada de *stringly typed*.

Pra usar direito você quase precisa reproduzir "na mão" o que o banco de dados já faz pra você. O que anda na moda, mas não quer dizer que ela é boa.

## Quando usar

É claro que isso tem lá sua utilidade. Nada é tão ruim que não tenha caso de uso. Precisa saber usá-lo na medida certa quando ele resolve um problema que não pode ser resolvido de forma melhor. O problema ocorre quando a pessoa adota isso porque não sabe o que está fazendo.

Sempre que precisar de flexibilidade no esquema do modelo, ele é adequado. Dessa forma passa por cima da rigidez do modelo relacional. Esse exemplo acima nem é tão adequado já que ele simula o modelo relacional, mas o fiz para entender melhor como funciona vindo do relacional.

Ele faz mais sentido quando o usuário final pode determinar as colunas que precisam ser usadas. Seja por escolha entre várias opções, seja por livre criação. Se for por escolha entre opções vai compensar mais se realmente forem várias opções e quase sempre poucas serão usadas. Em criação livre, não tem outro jeito.

Alguns consideram o [NoSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/101) uma alternativa ao EAV ([funcionamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101)). Na verdade o NoSQL é o EAV pronto para o uso (pelo menos em algumas modalidades de NoSQL). O termo NoSQL é um pouco mal usado, na verdade o que eles querem dizer é NoRelational. Uma das grandes vantagens do NoSQL é justamente não ter esquema.

De fato se for para usar assim, tem grande chance de um banco de dados chamado NoSQL ser uma solução melhor (ou era, hoje muitos relacionais podem fazer o mesmo de forma simples, tecnologias evoluem). Mas só se precisa disso. Em um banco de dados relacional (SQL ou não) é fácil optar por partes serem assim, partes não. Não sei se dá para ter a mesma flexibilidade na maioria dos bancos chamados NoSQL, mas quase.

Alguns bancos de dados relacionais permitem otimizações para cenários de "esquemas abertos". Um exemplo é o SQL Server, não sei se o Oracle tem algo assim. Os bancos mais simples, como SQLite, não tem.

## Artigos

[Artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

[Exemplo de uso em artigo bem completo](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2013/12/22/the-anti-pattern-eavil-database-design/).

[Mais um artigo](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2110957/).

[Uma comparação de modelos](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1619660-OTLT-EAV-design-why-do-people-hate-it).

[Resposta no SO mostrando algumas dificuldades](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4066568/221800).

Comment: Muito esclarecedor, o pessoal está mesmo querendo usar esta estrutura, argumentando que aumenta a performance, e possibilita, mais consistência dos dados, e eu não tinha ideia se valeria a pena, agora que eu ganhei um pouco mais de noção da coisa, dá pra cogitar a ideia de talvez não ter que adotá-la. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

O nome por si próprio já é bem explicativo. Este padrão serve para trazer uma certa dinamicidade na estrutura dos dados que serão salvos no banco de dados.

Como você bem deve saber, geralmente cria-se uma tabela para representar uma determinada informação, onde cada coluna desta tabela representará um atributo do dado guardado. Tomemos como exemplo uma tabela **`Pessoas`**.

```
Pessoas
Id      Nome      Idade      Sexo      Twitter      Facebook
---------------------------------------------------------------
1       Mario     37         M         @mario.2     fb.com/ma
2       José      21         N         @jose.3      fb.com/ze
```

O padrão EAV te dá a possibilidade de "desengessar" essas informações de forma que os atributos de `Pessoa` deixem de ser representados por colunas e passem a ser representados por linhas em outra tabela. A relação de uma entidade com os atributos e valores é feita então por meio de relações entre as tabelas.

Perceba que usando esta abordagem os atributos podem ser criados "em tempo de execução", afinal não é necessário mudar a estrutura das sua tabela para adicionar novos atributos. E também, acho importante ressaltar que integridade dos dados fica um tanto quanto comprometida, afinal, na maioria dos casos a coluna que salva o valor dos atributos será do tipo texto.

Veja um exemplo:

```
Pessoas           Atributos          Valores
Id      Nome      Id      Descr      IdPessoa    IdAtributo      Valor
--------------   ----------------   --------------------------------------
1       Ari       1       Idade      1           1               37         
2       José      2       Sexo       1           2               M
                  3       Twitter    1           3               @mario.2
                  4       Facebook   1           4               fb.com/ma
                                     2           1               21
                                     2           2               M
                                     2           3               @jose.3
                                     2           4               fb.com/ze
```

Veja também essa pergunta:

- [Alternativas para o (anti-)padrão Entity-Attribute-Value](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15534/91)

Comment: Ainda que fique claro para mim, como "funcionaria", não consegui visualizar um modelo prático disso. O relacionamento eu até entendo, só não consegui ainda criar uma estrutura funcional disso... gostaria de um exemplo prático, ao meu ver, nesta outra pergunta, só temos a resolução de parte do problema, na prática, tudo é muito diferente.

Comment: O que você quer saber é **quando deve usar** este modelo, isso?

Comment: Na verdade o @bigown conseguiu esclarecer de forma clara o que eu queria. Mas obrigado pela sua resposta, também foi muito útil para introdução do significado deste (anti-)padrão.