# Modelagem de dados: Integridade x Performance

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, desempenho, modelagem

Na empresa em que eu trabalho, existe um arquitetura de dados que eu nunca havia visto anteriormente, e gostaria de saber se é comum isso, ou se é uma nova tendência de mercado. Só pra constar o banco é Oracle. Aqui estão alguns pontos:

- Quase não existe relacionamento entre as tabelas, por exemplo, em uma das tabelas existe um campo que representa os id's de outra tabela, porém este mesmo campo não é um chave estrangeira, e sim um campo inteiro qualquer, logo qualquer valor pode ser salvo lá. A responsabilidade de garantir a integridade dos dados está na API que acessa esse banco. Logo quando  chega um POST, por exemplo, querendo salvar nesse campo, que na minha concepção deveria ser chave estrangeira, ele faz um select nessa na outra tabela, para verificar se esse valor existe, e se sim, então ele salva.
- Existem vários banco de dados, ou seja, existe um banco de dados para cada assunto da empresa, mesmo que essas tabelas de bancos diferentes poderiam muito bem estar relacionadas.
- Existe bastante redundância. Nesse ponto eu até entendo, pois existe a questão da 'desnormalização' em pró do desempenho, mas nesse caso, pelo menos na minha concepção está beirando ao extremo.

Eu questionei a pessoa que fez a modelagem, e o principal argumento foi em relação ao desempenho. Logo, todo as responsabilidades em relação aos dados, integridade, regra de negócio, estão na API. Eu iniciei no mercado de trabalho a pouco tempo, e gostaria de saber se essa é uma nova tendência de mercado.

Comment: Sempre me preocupei muito com desempenho, e entendi que seu eu fizer uma boa arquitetura de dados, usar os recursos de forma adequada, usar os relacionamentos entre entidades, sempre terei um bom desempenho, para ser sincero não consigo entender como redundância alguma poderia melhorar o desempenho, pior ainda , não utilizar as chaves estrangeiras que contém índices e ajudam muito nas consultas. Pensando bem até entendo a redundância de dados, pois como não há modelagem de forma adequada, quem concebeu essa estrutura, usou esse recurso para melhorar o desempenho.

Comment: Porem se tive-se adotado uma modelagem adequada, a redundância se tornaria desnecessária.

Comment: @RodrigoK.B O fato de você não entender não significa que não tenha vantagens, isto até é um fato bastante conhecido.

Comment: @Maniero ok, talvez eu tenha me expressado mal, mas eu já vi esse tipo de abordagem, de programadores utilizarem redundância para diminuir joins em suas consultas. O que quero dizer é que se a modelagem de dados for bem feita, isso se torna desnecessário. Pensando em desempenho, percebi que uma boa modelagem é mais eficiente do que redundância. Esse tipo de abordagem pode até te ajudar nas consultas, mas pode gerar  problemas na manutenção dos dados pro exemplo. Logo me pergunto, até onde isso é eficiente. Dai vem o que eu disse "Não consigo entender como isso melhora o desempenho".

Comment: Esta se falando de velocidade e não qualquer eficiência. Concordo com os outros aspectos.

Comment: @Maniero agradeço pelas observações.

Comment: *"responsabilidade de garantir a integridade dos dados está na API"* Isso está muito errado. O SGBD faz isso e de forma muito mais eficiente e segura. Já viu muito esse tipo de abordagem e geralmente leva a muita manutenção e problemas que poderiam ser evitados com as devidas FKs e índices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que você relata, um banco de dados para cada assunto da empresa, muita coisa *desnormalizada* e regras em *webapis*. Provavelmente na empresa que você trabalha estão utilizando, ou pelo menos tentando utilizar, uma arquitetura de *micro serviços* (ou *microservices*).

*Micro serviços* precisa ter um banco para cada serviço pelo motivo deles serem independentes. O segredo da performance nesse caso não está relacionado a ter (ou não) *foreign keys*, mas em conseguir quebrar seu sistema em vários servidores distintos, dividindo todo o processamento.

Com relação a sua pergunta referente a ser uma tendencia, acredito que *micro serviços* está mais para uma opção do que tendencia, pois uma arquitetura de *micro serviços* só se justifica se houver muita, mas muita demanda de acesso simultâneo. Exemplo: um site da *Amazon* ou *Mercado Livre*, pois uma arquitetura desse tipo se torna muito complexa e cara.

Por exemplo, o *StackOverflow* que recebe milhões de requisições — segundo uma palestra que assisti de uma desenvolvedora da plataforma —, possui uma arquitetura simples, nada de *DDD* e nem *micro serviços* mas é super performático. Portanto, você que está começando agora na área, tome muito cuidado com modismos.

Vou te indicar um vídeo muito bom para vocêrefletir sobre *micro serviços*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ValESAojRSw

Answer (score 5):

Se entendi bem isso é a [sexta forma normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form) ou [EAV](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138621/101) (Entity Attribute Value). E é usada em alguns casos. Estão usando cada vez mais, e em alguns casos, abusado.

E parece ter aberto mão das transações, do ACID.

Parece errado fazer isso no Oracle. Se é para fazer assim provavelmente um dos chamados [NoSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/101) sejam mais adequados. Mas só vendo a real situação para afirmar.

Redundância por si só não é problema, mas pode ser dependendo do caso. Há casos que é até obrigatório.

De forma geral o que foi exposto deve trazer problemas de desempenho. Peça para ele demonstrar que o desempenho é clara e objetivamente melhor. Duvido, a não ser pela redundância em alguns casos. Se tudo for baseado nisso, até pode ser. Depende da carga de leitura e de escrita, e dos padrões de escrita.

Existe muita coisa que as pessoas exageram no uso de banco de dados. Nem sempre precisa tudo o que o banco de dados tem, mas o seu também parece ser um caso exagerado ao contrário. E vou arriscar a dizer que a pessoa seguiu uma receita de bolo querendo fazer uma torta. Mas posso estar enganado. A descrição do problema aqui pode estar errada, pode ser que o contexto exija isso mesmo, enfim, só uma especulação.

De fato parece ser uma tendência, uma péssima diga-se de passagem. Minha percepção é que isso é necessário em uma quantidade ínfima de casos. Pragmáticos fazem o que precisa e quase todos os problemas se encaixam maravilhosamente bem no modelo relacional, sem exageros.

[Regra de negócio na aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15746/101) ([API é outra coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101), ela não tem implementação) é bastante comum e desejável na imensa maioria dos cenários. Em alguns casos sai muito caro colocar a regra de negócio na aplicação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado. Com relação à Integridade de dados (relacionamento entre tabelas), isso prejudica a performance?

Comment: Depende do jeito que é feito, mas costuma prejudicar. Mas fazer na aplicação não vai ajudar, na verdade tende a prejudicar mais. A não ser que a abandone.

Comment: E em relação a criação de vários bancos de dados, mesmo que existam tabelas que poderiam estar relacionadas? Quando eu questionei isso, me foi dito que se der algum problema em um dos bancos, isso não pararia as outras consultas. Esse argumento é correto, isso é considerado uma boa prática?

Comment: Isso é a ideia de microsserviços. Se parar uma, pode comprometer toda a consistência. Você pode abrir mão da consistência? Pra mim vai ficando claro que fizeram algo que não sabem as consequências, a não ser que tenha um justificativa plausível ou falte informações para sabermos sobre o fato real.