# Como determinar o tipo de dados a usar neste caso flexível?

Tags: mysql, sql, modelagem, varchar

O projeto consiste num banco de dados para fichas de RPG (D&D e afins). Ficou assim:

> **Database**
>   ficha
>
> **Tabelas**
>
> - personagem
> - sistema
> - raca
> - classe
> - atributo
> - personagem_atributo
>
> **Relacionamentos**
>
> - PERSONAGEM = N ======== 1 = SISTEMA
> - PERSONAGEM = N ======== 1 = RAÇA
> - PERSONAGEM = N ======== 1 = CLASSE
> - PERSONAGEM = N ======== N = ATRIBUTO == PERSONAGEM_ATRIBUTO

Na tabela de "atributo" existem atributos que podem conter textos (ex: Background), números (ex: Pontos de força = 15), textos e números (ex: Arco, Dano distância 2D6, Dano corpo a corpo 1D6).

Como faço posso criar isso na tabela `personagem_atributo`?

Pensei em criar uma coluna (atributo) com o nome `valor` com o tipo `varchar`, mas dessa forma eu fico preso a apenas o tipo `varchar`. Como faço para conseguir atribuir tipo ao valor de acordo com a informação fornecida (`int`, `text`, `varchar`)?

Comment: Sua pergunta vai de encontro ao conceito dos bancos RELACIONAIS, porém a unica solução que conheço pra sua duvida está na estrutura de Bancos NoSQL. Nesse tipo de banco cada tupla tem sua tipagem individualizada e mutável nas próximas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Ainda sou novo na área então desculpe se as perguntas são básicas. Mas atualmente ainda é utilizado a forma NoSQL? Eu vi que o modelo relacional é o mais atual então pensei que esse seria o melhor modelo a ser utilizado em banco de dados.

Comment: Se o valor pode ser alfanumérico, então não há dúvidas, terá de ser `VARCHAR`. Acho que não há necessidade de complicar. Se depois precisar pode fazer um `CAST` para o tipo que precisar!

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @HidemitsuGoncalvesHashimoto A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Não há problema algum em fazer isso em uma banco de dados relacional. Pode eventualmente para isso não ser o mais adequado, mas se você sair do relacional e quase todo o resto você precisa do relacional então você entrar em problema maior ainda. É melhor ter o ideal na maior parte e o menos ideal no resto, mas que está correto também.

Você vai trabalhar com chave e valor. Tem várias formas de fazer isso. Mas terá que tratar meio manualmente, mas quase sempre não muito diferente do que teria que fazer em um [NoSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/101), afinal ele não faz milagre, ele te libera do *schema*, mas não de ter que lidar com coisas que nem sabe o que é exatamente.

Em alguns casos você pode fazer mais simples, mas me parece que você quer é usar o [padrão EAV](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138621/101). Claro que os identificadores podem ser enumerações, ou até *strings*, mas é muito pior e custa muito mais, geralmente sem necessidade, como o NoSQL faz. Eu acho até ideal que o `id` da coluna seja usado e em uma tabela auxiliar da colunas disponíveis você tenha indicando de que tipo ela é para dar mais informações do que precisa. Isto é muito mais eficiente do que o modelo usado em NoSQL.

Na verdade quase sempre o modelo NoSchema do NoSQL (nome errado da tecnologia) e do EAV adotado é errado e seria melhor fazer um relacional. Tem poucos casos que a falta do *schema* realmente é uma boa solução, mesmo que dê mais trabalho fazer com *schema*.